# Google Colab "string_int_label_map_pb2.py" problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab and I am getting `string_int_label_map_pb2.py` error. How can I fix it on Google colab? I think I need to upload a protoco, but I don't know how to do this in colab.Please help.

This is my code

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

Comment: Please can you share complete error trace ?